# Prevent multiple running of a server side method

Tags: c#, asp.net, semaphore

I have a webpage with a button that does postback, connects to an external database to download some data and perform some database updates. The issue I have is the possibility that two or more people runs this download simultaneously or while the function is still running, which may cause problems.

How do I create some form of semaphore so that if the second person clicks the button, he'll get a message saying it's currently being updated?

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper transaction on your external database and apply row locking there as needed; the DB system should handle the concurrency just fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the first sight, I would use an ASP.NET Application variable enclosed in a lock statement to check and update it if needed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!GetSem_SomeoneIsDownloading())
    {
        PerformDownload();
        ClearSem_SomeoneIsDownloading();
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayMessageSomeoneIsDownloadingAlready();
    }
}

bool GetSem_SomeoneIsDownloading()
{
    bool isSomeoneDownloading;
    Application.Lock();

    isSomeoneDownloading = (bool)(Application["SomeoneIsDownloading"] ?? false);
    if (!isSomeoneDownloading)
        Application["SomeoneIsDownloading"] = true;

    Application.UnLock();
    return isSomeoneDownloading;
}

void ClearSem_SomeoneIsDownloading()
{
    Application.Lock();
    Application["SomeoneIsDownloading"] = false;
    Application.UnLock();
}
```